# Styling h3 h4 and p tags using grid

Tags: css

I have the following html

```
<div class="post-inner"> <h3 class="post-header"><a class="post-title" href="http://www.yellowfishjobs.com/job/sales-representative/">Sales Representative</a></h3>
<p class="post-excerpt"></p><h4>Location: Belfast</h4>
<h4>Job Type: Full-time</h4>
<p> <a href="http://www.yellowfishjobs.com/job/sales-representative/#more-2222" class="more-link">(more…)</a></p>
</div>
```

Which displays like this:

> Sales Representative
>   Location: Belfast
>   Job Type: Full-time
>   (more…)

I would like to display it like this:

> Sales Representative     Location: Belfast    Job Type: Full-time   (more…)

So that all posts line up in columns (Ie with all locations under each other).

I have never used display:grid before, so this is what I have tried:

```
.listing_page .post-inner {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px ;
}

.listing_page .post-inner h3 {grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: row1-start
  grid-row-end: 1}
.listing_page .post-inner h4:nth-child(1) {grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: row1-start
  grid-row-end: 1}
.listing_page .post-inner h4:nth-child(2) {grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: row1-start
  grid-row-end: 1}
.listing_page .post-inner p {grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: row1-start
  grid-row-end: 1}
```

but it does not seem to be having any effect. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? - Also, I want to do this only with CSS, without changing any html!
Thanks!

Comment: why can't you try with float:left ?

Comment: Because I want tidy columns

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you actually want...but with the info we have, using `display: inline-block;` for all child elements works fine:

```css
.post-inner > * { 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="post-inner"> 
  <h3 class="post-header"><a class="post-title" href="http://www.yellowfishjobs.com/job/sales-representative/">Sales Representative</a></h3>
  <p class="post-excerpt"></p><h4>Location: Belfast</h4>
  <h4>Job Type: Full-time</h4>
  <p> <a href="http://www.yellowfishjobs.com/job/sales-representative/#more-2222" class="more-link">(more…)</a></p>
</div>
```

Obviously, if you need to only target those items, you can create a helper class (such as `.inline-block`) and apply that helper class to the specific items you want to display inline.

Comment: Yeah - but I was hoping to have various posts below each other with matching columns

Comment: I don't understand what's preventing you from doing that, with the solution I provided, given the code you provided.

Comment: There will be many occurrences with similar posts below this with different lengths of words. I want there to be column for the job title, location, type with them all in tidy columns, like a spreadsheet...

Answer (score -1):

Though you asked not to change HTML but I had to answer changing HTML :P  :

```
  <table style="width=100%">
  <tr>
  <td width=25%>
  <div class="post-inner"> <h3 class="post-header"><a class="post-title" href="http://www.yellowfishjobs.com/job/sales-representative/">Sales Representative</a></h3></div>
</td>
<td width=25%>
  <p class="post-excerpt"></p><h4>Location: Belfast</h4>
  </td>
  <td width=25%>
<h1>Job Type: Full-time</h1>
</td>
<td width=25%>
<p> <a href="http://www.yellowfishjobs.com/job/sales-representative/#more-2222" class="more-link">(more…)</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
 </body></html>
```